# DdeConnect Fails with DMLERR_NO_CONV_ESTABLISHED

Tags: c++, winapi, dde

I'm trying to create a minimal DDE client & server to validate that I have a correct understanding of how to use [Dynamic Data Exchange Management Library (DDEML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/about-the-ddeml).

I have two simple Visual C++ 2019 projects with the following settings:

- Configuration Propertes -> General -> Platform Toolset Visual Studio 2017 -> **Windows XP (v141_xp)**
- C/C++ -> Language -> Conformance mode -> **No**
- Linker -> Subsystem -> **Windows**

**DdeServer.cpp**

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

HDDEDATA CALLBACK DdeCallback(
    UINT uType,       // transaction type 
    UINT uFmt,        // clipboard data format 
    HCONV hconv,      // handle to conversation 
    HSZ hsz1,         // handle to string 
    HSZ hsz2,         // handle to string 
    HDDEDATA hdata,   // handle to global memory object 
    DWORD dwData1,    // transaction-specific data 
    DWORD dwData2)    // transaction-specific data 
{
    switch (uType)
    {
    case XTYP_REGISTER:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_REGISTER" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_UNREGISTER:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_UNREGISTER" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_ADVDATA:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_ADVDATA" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)DDE_FACK;

    case XTYP_XACT_COMPLETE:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_XACT_COMPLETE" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_CONNECT:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_CONNECT" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_DISCONNECT:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_DISCONNECT" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    default:
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
        case WM_DESTROY:
        case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
        default:
        {
            return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
        }
    }
    return(0L);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole(); 
    FILE* new_stdout;
    freopen_s(&new_stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    DWORD pidInst = 0;
    UINT uResult = 0;
    uResult = DdeInitializeA(
        &pidInst,
        DdeCallback,
        APPCLASS_MONITOR |  // this is a monitoring application 
        MF_CALLBACKS |      // monitor callback functions 
        MF_CONV |           // monitor conversation data 
        MF_ERRORS |         // monitor DDEML errors 
        MF_HSZ_INFO |       // monitor data handle activity 
        MF_LINKS |          // monitor advise loops 
        MF_POSTMSGS |       // monitor posted DDE messages 
        MF_SENDMSGS,        // monitor sent DDE messages 
        0);                // reserved

    HSZ ddeService = DdeCreateStringHandleA(pidInst, "MyDdeServer", CP_WINANSI);
    DdeNameService(pidInst, ddeService, 0, DNS_REGISTER);
    
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return(msg.wParam);
}
```

**DdeClient.cpp**

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

HDDEDATA CALLBACK DdeCallback(
    UINT uType,       // transaction type 
    UINT uFmt,        // clipboard data format 
    HCONV hconv,      // handle to conversation 
    HSZ hsz1,         // handle to string 
    HSZ hsz2,         // handle to string 
    HDDEDATA hdata,   // handle to global memory object 
    DWORD dwData1,    // transaction-specific data 
    DWORD dwData2)    // transaction-specific data 
{
    switch (uType)
    {
    case XTYP_REGISTER:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_REGISTER" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_UNREGISTER:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_UNREGISTER" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_ADVDATA:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_ADVDATA" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)DDE_FACK;

    case XTYP_XACT_COMPLETE:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_XACT_COMPLETE" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_CONNECT:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_CONNECT" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    case XTYP_DISCONNECT:
        std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_DISCONNECT" << std::endl;
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;

    default:
        return (HDDEDATA)NULL;
    }
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
    case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
    default:
    {
        return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
    }
    }
    return(0L);
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole(); // Allocs a console if you do not have one.
    FILE* new_stdout;
    freopen_s(&new_stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    DWORD pidInst = 0;
    UINT uResult = 0;
    uResult = DdeInitializeA(
        &pidInst,
        DdeCallback,
        APPCLASS_MONITOR |  // this is a monitoring application 
        MF_CALLBACKS |      // monitor callback functions 
        MF_CONV |           // monitor conversation data 
        MF_ERRORS |         // monitor DDEML errors 
        MF_HSZ_INFO |       // monitor data handle activity 
        MF_LINKS |          // monitor advise loops 
        MF_POSTMSGS |       // monitor posted DDE messages 
        MF_SENDMSGS,        // monitor sent DDE messages 
        0);

    HSZ stringHandle = DdeCreateStringHandleA(pidInst, "MyDdeClient", CP_WINANSI);
    DdeNameService(pidInst, stringHandle, 0, DNS_REGISTER);

    HSZ ddeService = DdeCreateStringHandleA(pidInst, "MyDdeServer", CP_WINANSI);
    HSZ ddeTopic = DdeCreateStringHandleA(pidInst, "MyDdeTopic", CP_WINANSI);
    HCONV hConv = DdeConnect(pidInst, ddeService, ddeTopic, NULL);
    if (hConv == 0L)
    {
        UINT ddeLastError = DdeGetLastError(pidInst);
        std::cout << "DDE connect failed error#" << ddeLastError << std::endl;

    }
    
    std::cout << "Wating..." << std::endl;
    
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return(msg.wParam);
}
```

However, `DdeConnect()` was failing with error 16390, which is `DMLERR_INVALIDPARAMETER`.

According to the [`DdeGetLastError` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ddeml/nf-ddeml-ddegetlasterror), this is typically caused by one of the following issues:

> - The application used a data handle initialized with a different item name handle than was required by the transaction.
> - The application used a data handle that was initialized with a different clipboard data format than was required by the transaction.
> - The application used a client-side conversation handle with a server-side function or vice versa.
> - The application used a freed data handle or string handle.
> - More than one instance of the application used the same object.

Based on feedback in comments this error was caused by pidInst not being initialized to 0. Once this was fixed the error became **DMLERR_NO_CONV_ESTABLISHED** which means "A client's attempt to establish a conversation has failed."

However, I've been unable to pinpoint exactly where the issue is. I'm trying to work out what I need to change in order for `DdeConnect()` to work. I'm not seeing the server get XTYP_CONNECT event.

Comment: Are you playing with DDEML because you need to interact with another component that uses DDE? That's really the only valid use case for DDE any more. You shouldn't try to use it for anything new.

Comment: I don't want to use DDE but I'm debugging my 16-bit Windows emulation layer to try and run a business critical Visual Basic 3 application with lost source code on 64-bit Windows 10. It uses DDE to communicate between two components via VB3 runtime. I'm emulating 16-bit CPU instructions and intercepting the Win16 API calls and attempting to get them to work with Win32 APIs, everything is working except DDE stuff.

Comment: My goal is to get a Win32 app working first confirming my correct understanding of how DDE should work before I get too deep into the matrix debugging my 16-bit emulation layer

Comment: This is unrelated, maybe, though it's odd that your *DdeServer.cpp* sets `_WIN32_WINNT` **after** `#include <Windows.h>`.

Comment: Also unrelated to this question, but have you considered decompiling the VB3 executable? From what I understand it should be possible to get something that's very close to the original source code.

Comment: You *must* initialize client's pidInst to 0 before calling DdeInitialize, not leave it uninitialized. Also DdeCallback should use UINT_PTR dwData args instead of DWORD (not a big issue and unrelated to your real problem). And then you must handle the incoming XTYP_CONNECT in the server obviously.

Comment: Yes I decompiled the VB3 app to work out it uses DDE, but it it still huge project and while close to original source, not all parts decompile such as the controls it uses, etc. While they could be re-written it is a much bigger reversing effort some of the controls

Comment: Changing the title and the question after comments that solved it is dishonest.

Comment: It's not solved my problem, I still can't connect, my goal is to get DdeConnect to work which was in original question.

Comment: Note that your matrix will get significant more complicated once you try converting 16-bit DDE to 32-bit DDE. (They use different parameter-passing models. If you need only have the two apps communicate with each other, a custom marshaler may be better than trying to generically support 16/32 DDE interop.,) In 16-bit, DDE is just posting atoms and HGLOBALs to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be gleaned from reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ddeml/nf-ddeml-ddeinitializea):

> **APPCLASS_MONITOR**
>
> Makes it possible for the application to monitor DDE activity in the system. **This flag is for use by DDE monitoring applications.** The application specifies the types of DDE activity to monitor by combining one or more monitor flags with the APPCLASS_MONITOR flag. For details, see the following Remarks section.

> Remarks
>
> **A DDE monitoring application should not attempt to perform DDE operations (establish conversations, issue transactions, and so on) within the context of the same application instance.**

In other words, APPCLASS_MONITOR is intended only for a DDE monitoring/debugging application. DDE applications that provide DDE services should not specify that flag.

Answer (score -1):

Three items needed to be resolved for DdeConnect to work:

1. As pointed out in comments ensure pidInst is initialized to 0 before calling DdeInitialize

   DWORD pidInst = 0;
   UINT uResult = 0;
   uResult = DdeInitializeA(
   &pidInst,
   DdeCallback,
   etc
2. Modify server DdeInitializeA to only specify APPCMD_FILTERINITS for afCmd
3. In server callback return DDE_FACK for XTYPE_CONNECT

case XTYP_CONNECT:
std::cout << "DDE Callback XTYP_CONNECT" << std::endl;
return (HDDEDATA)DDE_FACK;